# How to show notification after running the app?

Tags: android, leadbolt

Hi Im such a novice in android programming and leadbolt altogether.

I have successfully created sample apps for ads, banners, and walls. Right now Im creating for notifications which Im really having a problem.

Im using the latest leadbolt sdk (3.06) and for notifications Im using the **pubxapp.jar**.

In my settings, I set Notification Type to **On Demand** so I can see the notification while my app is running.

In my main activity class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // I used the actual leadbolt section id in my actual sample app.
    myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "MY_LEADBOLT_SECTION_ID");
    myController.loadNotification();
}
```

In my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.pad.android.xappad.AdNotification" />
    <receiver android:name="com.pad.android.xappad.AdReminderNotification" />
    <receiver android:name="com.example.leadbolttestappnotification.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: have you got any answer regarding this ...? bcoz i m also stuck with the same problem...help will be appreciated..